# read Excel file using Ole db cannot read all the excel rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, excel, connection-string, oledb, sqlconnection

I'm making  MVC3 application and i need to read excel file using Ole db connection but it cannot get all the excel rows on some machines and can get all data on others . the following is my code:

```
var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml", serverPath);

            //Fill the dataset with information from the Hoja1 worksheet.
            string SqlCommand="SELECT * FROM [sheet1$] ";

            var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SqlCommand, connectionString);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "results");
            DataTable data = ds.Tables["results"];
```

I nees to know the reason for this problm
Thanks alot

Comment: Are you using the same file and same version of Excel on all machines?

Comment: Read & Write use Oledb & Odbs not cross platform(Not supported all Win versions(x64 & x86)) , try OpenXML option!,no problem wroked all machines.And not differences web and win app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!,good Q.I this time research your problem.And more yes options,
for example i see write:

1)WindowsBase & Core optimization - [enter link description here](http://www.sadev.co.za/content/reading-and-writing-excel-2007-or-excel-2010-c-part-v-full-source-reading)

2)OpenXML SDK (From Microsoft Project download see link [click here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) , it for MS Office read & write use XML & XSLT formated and no problem worked in Win & Web application).
No , 1-bad section it worked MS 2007,2010,... version.Not worked on MS 1997,2003???
For exampled article yet - [Article-1](http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/OpenXML-reading-the-cells-of-a-workbook.aspx),[Article-2](http://debugmode.net/2011/10/08/reading-excel-file-in-a-collection-using-open-xml-sdk-2-0/),[Article-3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2008/11/10/reading-data-from-spreadsheetml.aspx),...

,and more yet options...

Try  top articles!

Comment: Official docs in yet more examples,[click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg575571.aspx) and from ms blog [simple read](http://blogs.msdn.com/brian_jones/archive/2008/11/10/reading-data-from-spreadsheetml.aspx)